# Resharper 6 works slow with jQuery

Tags: jquery, resharper, freeze

Did someone notice that resharper 6 hangs when typing jQuery.append, jQuery.trigger etc.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Not understanding this close vote for being "off topic".  Seems clearly to fall under the heading of "software tools commonly used by programmers" which are explicitly allowed.

Answer (score 6):

Resharper 6 worked really slow on my machine.. I basically could do nothing (type, browsing etc.). Clearing cache does not help. I switched back to 5.1.3 and will wait for 6.1 improvements (if they are)

Comment: It's JS and CSS support for the code editor is ridiculously slow, almost unsuable.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Select ReSharper > Options > General, and hit **Clear caches**
2. Try disabling other VS plug-ins. For example, Atlassian VS Connector
   could be the [cause of the issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-273820) but other plug-ins could cause this as well.
3. If 1 and 2 doesn't help, provide JetBrains with a [performance profile](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Profiling+Instructions),
   and we'll investigate the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Clearing of cashes didnt help. Plugins are disabled. Created an issue as you described. http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-273989?projectKey=RSRP

Comment: Thank you! Raised priority of the issue. I'm expecting the responsible developer to investigate in the coming days.